# Capture HTML after element has been changed

Tags: automated-testing

I am looking for automated way to capture HTML after I do some actions on the web page.

For example I select some item in dropdown and HTML changes- I want to capture that HTML and dump into file. As result I will end up with many different HTML files on my hdd.

I was thinking it might be possible to achieve that by using Selenium, or maybe some other plugin which would give me possibility to save HTML in automatic manner to file.

Thanks for your advices!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In fact any sniffer tool has required functionality. The most popular are [Fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler) and [Wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/). The simplest example is [HTTPFox](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/httpfox/) extension for Firefox browser.

You can also use [Apache JMeter](http://jmeter.apache.org/) as it capable of capturing HTTP requests and write responses into files.

Reference material:

- [JMeter's Superpower: The HTTP Proxy Server](https://blazemeter.com/blog/jmeters-superpower-http-proxy-server)
- [Apache JMeter proxy Step-by-step](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.pdf)
- [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP(S)_Test_Script_Recorder)

Comment: You are right, Dima, thank you very much!